# Getting twitter data into a Meteor app via the twitter API

Tags: meteor

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        checkTwitter: function () {
            this.unblock();
            return Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=perkytweets");
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.call("checkTwitter", function(error, results) {
        console.log(results.content); // should be a JSON object
    });
}
```

Next I want to add this result.context in my template just getting data.

Comment: When I try to request this url I get `{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}`

Comment: how can i get this on my template

Comment: Why do you want to integrate it to your template? Did you not read what it says? The Twitter Api v1 is no longer active. Does not make sense to use it.

Comment: @Jankapunkt its a demo api i just want to get data from api in template, get data from server to client-side and show data in screen in Meteor.js

Comment: Okay, understood now. So what error do you get exactly? Can you add it to the question?